# Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, ecmascript-6

I use Kendo UI, Angular and ES6, I am refactoring my code but I have this error, my create and update functions of kendo grid aren't fired anymore. I extend a class. Here is a sample of my code :

```
getTransport = {
        read: promise => {
          this.getDataForGrid(promise);
        },
        update: function(promise) { // eslint-disable-line
          this.updateForGrid(promise);
        }.bind(this),
        destroy: function(promise) { // eslint-disable-line
          this.destroyForGrid(promise);
        }.bind(this),
        create: function(promise) { // eslint-disable-line
          this.createForGrid(promise).then(data => { // eslint-disable-line
            this.grid.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
          });
        }.bind(this)
      };

getDataForGrid(promise) {
    this.$rootScope.isLoading = true;
    return this.serviceLinked.get()
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      promise.success(
        response
      );
      this.$rootScope.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  updateForGrid(promise) {
    console.log('update');
    this.$rootScope.isLoading = true;
    return this.serviceLinked.put(promise.data)
    .then(response => {
      promise.success(
        response.data
      );
      this.$rootScope.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  destroyForGrid(promise) {
    this.$rootScope.isLoading = true;
    return this.serviceLinked.delete(promise.data.id)
    .then(response => {
      promise.success(
        response.data
      );
      this.$rootScope.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  createForGrid(promise) {
    console.log('create')
    this.$rootScope.isLoading = true;
    return this.serviceLinked.post(promise.data);
  }
```

Can anyone please help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Check if it has to do with that fact that you are declaring the read transport as a promise and the update/destroy/create as "regular" functions.  All the transport configs need to be define the same way(all functions or all objects) to work(see http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read). Perhaps the mix of promise => syntax and function syntax causes the same issue?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error? It may be that Kendo UI cannot handle being passed strict-mode functions, in which case using ES6 classes may be a no-go.